# Use row values as columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following `brands` table with `total` sales per `month` as a result of a previous query:

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Apr-2012 | 100 |
| 123 | Mar-2012 | 150 |
| 123 | Jan-2012 | 500 |
| 987 | Apr-2012 | 5 |
| 987 | Mar-2012 | 0.10 |
| 987 | Feb-2012 | 8 |

I am looking to achieve the following:

| id | Apr-2012 | Mar-2012 | Feb-2012 | Jan-2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 100 | 150 | 0 | 500 |
| 987 | 5 | 0.10 | 8 | 0 |

How do I use the `date` values as column labels and fill in missing dates with 0 totals?

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgres, but you should probably have a look at the crosstab function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: What you want is a [Pivot(Crosstab for postgres)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)

Comment: @AntarrByrd damn, you're googling faster than I am :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS) query for your example would look like this:

To fill in `0` for resulting `NULL` values (request in comment), use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```sql
SELECT brand_id
     , COALESCE(jan, 0) AS "Jan-2012"
     , COALESCE(feb, 0) AS "Feb-2012"
     , COALESCE(mar, 0) AS "Mar-2012"
     , COALESCE(apr, 0) AS "Apr-2012"
FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT brand_id, month, total
        FROM   brands
        ORDER  BY 1'

       ,$$VALUES ('Jan-2012'::text), ('Feb-2012'), ('Mar-2012'), ('Apr-2012')$$
 ) AS ct (
   brand_id int
 , jan numeric    -- use actual data type!
 , feb numeric
 , mar numeric
 , apr numeric);
```

Detailed explanation and links:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Aside: I avoided the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL "date" as column name (even if Postgres allows it).

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. Any tip on how to fill in the blanks with 0s?

Comment: @Jamie: I added a solution for that.

Comment: Is there a way to not hardcode month names? For example get list from another query

Comment: @EugenKonkov: If you refer to output column names, that's not easily possible as SQL demands to know names and types of result columns up front. Maybe ask a question with all relevant details ...