# How to pivot or crosstab in postgresql without writing a function?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

[image: gotta pivot]

I'd like to aggregate all `co` values on one row, so the final result looks something like:

[image]

Seems pretty easy, right? Just write a query using `crosstab`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22887033/896802). Problem is that requires that I `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;` and I don't have write access to my DB.

Can anyone recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT co,
  MIN(CASE WHEN ontology_type = 'industry' THEN tags END) AS industry,
  MIN(CASE WHEN ontology_type = 'customer_type' THEN tags END) AS customer_type, 
  -- ...
FROM tab_name
GROUP BY co
```

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DO** to generate and **PREPARE** your own **SQL** with crosstab columns, then **EXECUTE** it.

```
-- replace tab_name to yours table name

DO $$
DECLARE
  _query text;
  _name text;
BEGIN
  _name := 'prepared_query';
  _query := '
    SELECT co
        '||(SELECT ', '||string_agg(DISTINCT 
                    ' string_agg(DISTINCT 
                                CASE ontology_type WHEN '||quote_literal(ontology_type)||' THEN tags 
                                ELSE NULL 
                                END, '',''
                                ) AS '||quote_ident(ontology_type),',') 
            FROM tab_name)||'
    FROM tab_name
    GROUP BY co
    ';

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'DEALLOCATE '||_name;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN invalid_sql_statement_name THEN
    END;

    EXECUTE 'PREPARE '||_name||' AS '||_query;
END
$$;

EXECUTE prepared_query;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Since Ver. 9.4 there's json_object_agg(), which lets us do part of the necessary magic dynamically.**

However to be totally dynamic, a *temp type (a temp table)* has to be *FIRST* built by running a SQL-EXEC inside ***an anonymous procedure.***

***[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL) (UK):***
https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL

***DISCLAIMER:** Typically the ability to create TEMP TABLES are granted to end-users, but YMMV. Another concern is whether anon. procedures can be exec'd as in-line code by regular users.*

```
-- /** 
-- begin test data 
-- begin test data 
-- begin test data 
--  */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpSales ;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpSales AS
SELECT
  sale_id
  ,TRUNC(RANDOM()*12)+1 AS book_id
  ,TRUNC(RANDOM()*100)+1 AS customer_id
  ,(date '2010-01-01' + random() * (timestamp '2016-12-31' - timestamp '2010-01-01')) AS sale_date
FROM generate_series(1,10000) AS sale_id;
     
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_month_total ; 
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_month_total AS 
SELECT
  date_part( 'year' , sale_date ) AS year
  ,date_part( 'month', sale_date ) AS mn 
  ,to_char(sale_date, 'mon') AS month
  ,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tmpSales
GROUP BY date_part('year', sale_date), to_char(sale_date, 'mon') ,date_part( 'month', sale_date ) 
    ;

DATA:
+----+--+-----+-----+
|year|mn|month|total|
+----+--+-----+-----+
|2010|1 |jan  |127  |
|2010|2 |feb  |117  |
|2010|3 |mar  |121  |
|2010|4 |apr  |131  |
|2010|5 |may  |106  |
|2010|6 |jun  |121  |
|2010|7 |jul  |129  |
|2010|8 |aug  |114  |
|2010|9 |sep  |115  |
|2010|10|oct  |110  |
|2010|11|nov  |133  |
|2010|12|dec  |108  |
+----+--+-----+-----+

-- /** 
-- END test data 
-- END test data 
-- END test data 
--  */


-- /** 
-- dyn. build a temporary row-type based on existing data, not hard-coded
-- dyn. build a temporary row-type based on existing data, not hard-coded
-- dyn. build a temporary row-type based on existing data, not hard-coded
--  **/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTblTyp CASCADE ; 
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ DECLARE v_sqlstring VARCHAR  = ''; BEGIN 
v_sqlstring := CONCAT( 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpTblTyp AS SELECT '   
                       ,(SELECT  STRING_AGG( CONCAT('NULL::int AS ' , month )::TEXT , ' ,' 
                            ORDER BY mn 
                       
                           )::TEXT
                           FROM
                           (SELECT DISTINCT month, mn FROM tmp_month_total )a )
                       ,' LIMIT 0 '    
                       ) ; -- RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sqlstring ;  
EXECUTE( v_sqlstring ) ; END $$; 
 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpMoToJson ;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpMoToJson AS
      SELECT 
         year AS year
         ,(json_build_array( months )) AS js_months_arr
         ,json_populate_recordset ( NULL::tmpTblTyp /** use temp table as a record type!! **/
                                  , json_build_array( months ) 
                                 ) jprs /** builds row-type column that can be expanded with (jprs).*   
                                         **/
      FROM ( SELECT year
             -- accum data into JSON array
             ,json_object_agg(month,total) AS months 
             FROM tmp_month_total
             GROUP BY year
             ORDER BY year
            ) a
; 

SELECT  
  year
,(ROW((jprs).*)::tmpTblTyp).* -- explode the composite type row
FROM tmpMoToJson ;



+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|year|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|2010|127|117|121|131|106|121|129|114|115|110|133|108|
|2011|117|112|117|115|139|116|119|152|117|112|115|103|
|2012|129|111|98 |140|109|131|114|110|112|115|100|121|
|2013|128|112|141|127|141|102|113|109|111|110|123|116|
|2014|129|114|117|118|111|123|106|111|127|121|124|145|
|2015|118|113|131|122|120|121|140|114|118|108|114|131|
|2016|117|110|139|100|110|116|112|109|131|117|122|132|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

As of postgres 9.4 you can use json_object_agg...

```
--set up a temp table with some rows to pivot into columns
    drop table _temp;
create temp table _temp(id serial, key int, header text, value text);
insert into _temp(key, header, value) values
    (1, 'a', 'this is a'),
    (1, 'b', 'this is b'),
    (1, 'c', 'this is c'),
    (2, 'a', 'this is a'),
    (2, 'b', 'this is b'),
    (3, 'c', 'this is c')
;

--pivot using json_object_agg
select  t.key,
        t.headers->>'a' as a,
        t.headers->>'b' as b,
        t.headers->>'c' as c
from    (
        select key, json_object_agg(header, value) as headers
        from _temp
        group by key
        ) t
order by key
;

/*
--results
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|key|a        |b        |c        |
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|1  |this is a|this is b|this is c|
|2  |this is a|this is b|null     |
|3  |null     |null     |this is c|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

*/

Answer (score -2):

By using pivot also we can achieve your required out put

```
SELECT co
    ,industry
    ,customer_type
    ,product_type
    ,sales_model
    ,stage
FROM dataSet
PIVOT(max(tags) FOR ontologyType IN (
            industry
            ,customer_type
            ,product_type
            ,sales_model
            ,stage
            )) AS PVT
```

Comment: As far as I can tell pivot is not available for Postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tablefunc.html