# Create pivot table with dynamic column names

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I am creating a pivot table which represents crash values for particular year. Currently, i am doing a hard code for column names to create pivot table. Is there anyway to make the column names dynamic to create pivot table? years are stored inside an array 
{2018,2017,2016 ..... 2008}

```sql
with crash as (
--- pivot table generated for total fatality ---
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab('SELECT b.id, b.state_code, a.year, count(case when a.type = ''Fatal'' then a.type end) as fatality
FROM  '||state_code_input||'_all as a, (select * from source_grid_repository where state_code = '''||upper(state_code_input)||''') as b
where st_contains(b.geom,a.geom) 
group by b.id, b.state_code, a.year
order by b.id, a.year',$$VALUES ('2018'),('2017'),('2016'),('2015'),('2014'),('2013'),('2012'),('2011'),('2010'),('2009'),('2008') $$) 
AS pivot_table(id integer, state_code varchar, fat_2018 bigint, fat_2017 bigint, fat_2016 bigint, fat_2015 bigint, fat_2014 bigint, fat_2013 bigint, fat_2012 bigint, fat_2011 bigint, fat_2010 bigint, fat_2009 bigint, fat_2008 bigint)
)
```

In the above code, fat_2018, fat_2017 , fat_2016 etc were hard coded. I need the years after fat_ to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times, & there are decent *(even dynamic)* solutions. While CROSSTAB() is available in recent versions of Postgres, not everyone has sufficient privileges to install the prerequisite extensions.

One such solution involves a *[temp type (temp table) created by an anonymous function & JSON expansion of the resultant type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/how-to-pivot-or-crosstab-in-postgresql-without-writing-a-function/73804975#73804975)*

See also: [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL) (UK): https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL

[How to pivot or crosstab in postgresql without writing a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/how-to-pivot-or-crosstab-in-postgresql-without-writing-a-function/73804975#73804975)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. PostgreSQL is strict type system. Result is a table (relation). A format of this table (columns, columns names, columns types) should be defined before query execution (in planning time). So you cannot to write any query for Postgres that returns dynamic number of columns.