# create dynamic column from a column with multi variables

Tags: postgresql, transpose, unpivot, postgresql-9.4

Looking to Split Hobby column to N multiple columns in PostgreSQL 9.4, where each column header shows the Hobby.

`Original table`

| Name | Hobby |
| --- | --- |
| Rene | Python, Monkey Bars |
| CJ | Trading, Python |
| Herlinda | Fashion |
| DJ | Consulting, Sales |
| Martha | Social Media, Teaching |
| Doug | Leadership, Management |
| Mathew | Finance, Emp Engagement |
| Meyers | Sleeping, Coding, CrossFit |
| Mike | YouTube, Athletics |
| Peter | Eat, Sleep, Python |
| Thomas | Read, Trading, Sales |

notes:
without using crosstab()

`Desire table`

[desire table result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPNcg.png)

| Name | Hobby | Python | Monkey Bars | Trading | Fashion | Consutling | Sales | Social Media | Teaching | Leadership | Management | Finance | Emp Engagement | Sleeping | Coding | Crossfit | YouTube | Athletics | Eat | Sleep | Read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rene | Python, Monkey Bars | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| CJ | Trading, Python | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Herlinda | Fashion | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| DJ | Consulting, Sales | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Martha | Social Media, Teaching | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Doug | Leadership, Management | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Mathew | Finance, Emp Engagement | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Meyers | Sleeping, Coding, CrossFit | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Mike | YouTube, Athletics | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Peter | Eat, Sleep, Python | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| Thomas | Read, Trading, Sales | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

---removing the 1NF
[removing the 1NF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llhhB.png)

```
CREATE TABLE ws_bi.split_clm(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  hobby text
);
INSERT INTO ws_bi.split_clm (id, name, hobby) VALUES
(1, 'Rene', 'Python, Monkey Bars'),
(2, 'CJ', 'Trading, Python'),
(3, 'Herlinda', 'Fashion'),
(4, 'DJ', 'Consulting, Sales'),
(5, 'Martha', 'Social Media, Teaching'),
(6, 'Doug', 'Leadership, Management'),
(7, 'Mathew', 'Finance, Emp Engagement'),
(8, 'Meyers', 'Sleeping, Coding, CrossFit'),
(9, 'Mike', 'YouTube, Athletics'),
(10, 'Peter', 'Eat, Sleep, Python'),
(11, 'Thomas', 'Read, Trading, Sales');
/***query****/
SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', ')) AS values 
FROM ws_bi.split_clm
ORDER BY id;
```

---

result image [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCxP9.png)

---**update March.2.2023.**
by using  this solution: **[stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/)**

[code creator: L. Rodgers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156698/l-rodgers)

DB FIDDLE (UK): https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL

Making some adjustment from the  L. Rodgers solution for some reason still falling... maybe because Json function are something very new for me.
[image result tmpMoToJson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uKZ8.png)

```
     ---sample data 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ws_bi.split_clm;
CREATE TABLE ws_bi.split_clm(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  hobby text, 
  value int
);
INSERT INTO ws_bi.split_clm (id, name, hobby,value) VALUES
(1, 'Rene', 'Python, Monkey_Bars','5'),
(2, 'CJ', 'Trading, Python','25'),
(3, 'Herlinda', 'Fashion','15'),
(4, 'DJ', 'Consutling, Sales','35'),
(5, 'Martha', 'Social_Media, Teaching','45'),
(6, 'Doug', 'Leadership, Management','55'),
(7, 'Mathew', 'Finance, Emp_Engagement','65'),
(8, 'Mayers', 'Sleeping, Coding, Crossfit','75'),
(9, 'Mike', 'YouTube, Athletics','85'),
(10, 'Peter', 'Eat, Sleep, Python','95'),
(11, 'Thomas', 'Read, Trading, Sales','105');
/****query****/
--1NF <done>
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ws_bi.split_clm_Nor;
  CREATE     TABLE     ws_bi.split_clm_Nor  AS  (
  SELECT id, name, unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', ')) AS Ivalues , value
  FROM ws_bi.split_clm
  ORDER BY id
--;
) with data
    DISTRIBUTED BY (id) ;
 Analyze  ws_bi.split_clm_Nor;
 --Select * from   ws_bi.split_clm_Nor limit 6; ---
 ---ver 2.0
 --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2;
  CREATE     TABLE     ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2  AS (
  SELECT id, name, lower(unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', '))) AS Ivalues , value,count(1)  as "Case_Volume"
  FROM ws_bi.split_clm
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ORDER BY id
--;
) with data
    DISTRIBUTED BY (id) ;
 Analyze  ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2;
 --Select * from   ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2 limit 6; 
 ---------------------------

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  ws_bi.tmpTblTyp2 CASCADE ; 
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ 
DECLARE v_sqlstring VARCHAR  = ''; 
BEGIN 
v_sqlstring := CONCAT( 'CREATE  TABLE ws_bi.tmpTblTyp2 AS SELECT '   
                       ,(SELECT  STRING_AGG( CONCAT('NULL::int AS ' , ivalues )::TEXT , ' ,' 
                            ORDER BY ivalues                        
                           )::TEXT
                           FROM
                           (SELECT DISTINCT ivalues  FROM ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2 )a
                        )
                      ,' LIMIT 0 '    
                       ) ; -- RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sqlstring ;  
EXECUTE( v_sqlstring ) ; END $$; 
 --------------------------------------------
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ws_bi.tmpMoJson ;
CREATE     TABLE     ws_bi.tmpMoJson  AS    (
--CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpMoJson AS
      SELECT 
         name AS name
         ,(json_build_array( mivalues )) AS js_mivalues_arr
         ,json_populate_recordset ( NULL::ws_bi.tmpTblTyp2 /** use temp table as a record type!!*/
                                   , json_build_array( mivalues )  /** builds row-type column that can be expanded with (jprs).* */
                                  ) jprs /**no error with wrong JSON values result under jprs**/
      FROM ( SELECT name
             ,json_object_agg(ivalues,value) AS mivalues 
             FROM ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2
             GROUP BY 1
             ORDER BY 1
            ) a
--;
) with data
    DISTRIBUTED BY (name) ;
 Analyze  ws_bi.tmpMoJson;
--Select * from   ws_bi.tmpMoJson;  
 SELECT  
  name
,(ROW((jprs).*)::ws_bi.tmpTblTyp2).* -- explode the composite type row
FROM ws_bi.tmpMoJson ;
```

DB FIDDLE (UK) before : https://dbfiddle.uk/BoyKmDrT

DB FIDDLE (UK) after :  https://dbfiddle.uk/gP0kAnZ5

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction. Multiple keys in a column violate [first-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and are going to cause you unending problems. You need to [normalize your database](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-database-normalization-in-sql-6b16544deb0)

Comment: got it.
removing the 1NF.

Comment: I'm new to using this site, so I'm terribly sorry if I accidentally erased some of the discussions. Because I see some of those conversations are gone and I don't see how to recover it

Comment: Without an error code, I am still unable to determine why 'jprs' shows only a series of comma symbols  instead of values with their comma symbol.

json_populate_recordset (null::ws_svc_gsa_bi.tmpTblTyp2, json_build_array( mivalues )  ) jprs

Comment: What will be the best approach to find out the reason to get no error with wrong JSON values result?

Comment: for  reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

Comment: resolved case sensitive was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get it work , just change to lower caps the column Ivalues  (hobby)

DB FIDDLE (UK) after : https://dbfiddle.uk/gP0kAnZ5

Answer (score 0):

I am not trying to use tablefunc/crosstab.

```
 ---ver 2.0
 --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2;
  CREATE     TABLE     ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2  AS (
  SELECT id, name, unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', ')) AS Ivalues 
  FROM ws_bi.split_clm
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  ORDER BY id
--;
) with data
    DISTRIBUTED BY (id) ;
 Analyze  ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2;
 --Select * from   ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2 limit 6;
```

---result of this last query in the image

```
SELECT  name
,json_object_agg(Ivalues, 'TRUE') AS Mains 
FROM   ws_bi.split_clm_Nor2
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY  name;
```

[picture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Uzo.png)

Comment: I'm going to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/

Comment: I'm new to using this site, so I'm terribly sorry if I accidentally erased some of the discussions. Because  I see some of those conversations are gone and I don't see how to recover it .

Comment: lol.. the issue is related to case sensitive :)