# Looking for a PL/PGSQL function to return N columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

Run in a PL/pgSQL a function to return N columns and put in a view or something that allow to get the table with the N column updated without human intervention.

Using the below code from:
[create dynamic column from a column with multi variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594224/)

```
---sample data 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  split_clm;
CREATE TEMP TABLE  split_clm(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  hobby text, 
  value int
);
INSERT INTO  split_clm (id, name, hobby,value) VALUES
(1, 'Rene', 'Python, Monkey_Bars','5'),
(2, 'CJ', 'Trading, Python','25'),
(3, 'Herlinda', 'Fashion','15'),
(4, 'DJ', 'Consutling, Sales','35'),
(5, 'Martha', 'Social_Media, Teaching','45'),
(6, 'Doug', 'Leadership, Management','55'),
(7, 'Mathew', 'Finance, Emp_Engagement','65'),
(8, 'Mayers', 'Sleeping, Coding, Crossfit','75'),
(9, 'Mike', 'YouTube, Athletics','85'),
(10, 'Peter', 'Eat, Sleep, Python','95'),
(11, 'Thomas', 'Read, Trading, Sales','105');
/****query****/
--1NF <done>
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  split_clm_Nor;
CREATE TEMP TABLE     split_clm_Nor  AS 
  SELECT id, name, unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', ')) AS Ivalues , value
  FROM  split_clm
  ORDER BY id;
-- 
 --Select * from    split_clm_Nor limit 6; ---
 ---ver 2.0
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  split_clm_Nor2;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE      split_clm_Nor2  AS
  SELECT id, name, lower(unnest(string_to_array(hobby, ', '))) AS Ivalues , value,count(1)  as "Case_Volume"
  FROM  split_clm
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ORDER BY id
;
Select * from    split_clm_Nor2  ; 
 ---------------------------
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmpTblTyp2 CASCADE ; 
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ 
DECLARE v_sqlstring VARCHAR  = ''; 
BEGIN 
v_sqlstring := CONCAT( 'CREATE  TABLE  tmpTblTyp2 AS SELECT '   
                      ,(SELECT  STRING_AGG( CONCAT('NULL::int AS ' , ivalues )::TEXT , ' ,' ORDER BY ivalues )::TEXT
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ivalues  FROM  split_clm_Nor2) a
                        )
                      ,' LIMIT 0 '    
                       ) ; -- RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sqlstring ;  
EXECUTE( v_sqlstring ) ; END $$; 
 --------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  tmpMoJson ;
CREATE TEMP TABLE     tmpMoJson  AS
--CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpMoJson AS
      SELECT 
         name AS name
         ,(json_build_array( mivalues )) AS js_mivalues_arr
         ,json_populate_recordset ( NULL::tmpTblTyp2 /** use temp table as a record type!!*/
                                   , json_build_array( mivalues )  /** builds row-type column that can be expanded with (jprs).* */
                                  ) jprs  
      FROM ( SELECT name
                   ,json_object_agg(ivalues,value) AS mivalues 
             FROM split_clm_Nor2
             GROUP BY 1
             ORDER BY 1
            ) a
;
Select * from    tmpMoJson  ; 
 SELECT  
  name
,(ROW((jprs).*):: tmpTblTyp2).* -- explode the composite type row
--, js_mivalues_arr /** optional **/
FROM  tmpMoJson ;
```

Expecting get that table continue update

| name | athletics | coding | consutling | crossfit | eat | emp_engagement | fashion | finance | leadership | management | monkey_bars | python | read | sales | sleep | sleeping | social_media | teaching | trading | youtube |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CJ | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 25 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 25 | null |
| DJ | null | null | 35 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 35 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Doug | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 55 | 55 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Herlinda | null | null | null | null | null | null | 15 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Martha | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 45 | 45 | null | null |
| Mathew | null | null | null | null | null | 65 | null | 65 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Mayers | null | 75 | null | 75 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 75 | null | null | null | null |
| Mike | 85 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 85 |
| Peter | null | null | null | null | 95 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 95 | null | null | 95 | null | null | null | null | null |
| Rene | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 5 | 5 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Thomas | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 105 | 105 | null | null | null | null | 105 | null |

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: Because I’m using postgresql-9.4, what will be my options to keep this JSON query up-to-date? I need to update the last query every time I call it to get the last data set.
--------
 `SELECT  
  name
,(ROW((jprs).*):: tmpTblTyp2).* -- explode the composite type row
--, js_mivalues_arr /** optional **/
FROM  tmpMoJson ;
`

Comment: [Postgres 9.4 has reached EOL in 2020](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a function that returns a dynamic number of columns without hard coding the list of columns at some place (either when calling the function or when defining the function).

The best (only?) option I see, is to create a view that is based on the content of the table. You can then call that view each time the table changes to create a new view with the updated list of columns.

```
create function create_clm_view()
 returns void
as
$body$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_columns text;
  l_hobby_name text;
begin
  l_sql := 'select name, ';

  -- build the list of columns based on the distinct hobbies
  select string_agg(format('%L = any(hobbies) as %I', x.hobby_name, x.hobby_name), ', ' order by hobby_name)
    into l_columns
  from (
    select distinct t.hobby_name
    from split_clm s
      cross join unnest(regexp_split_to_array(s.hobby, '\s*,\s*')) as t(hobby_name)
  ) x;

  -- build the final SELECT of the view with the generated columns
  l_sql := l_sql || l_columns ||
  $sql$ from ( select name, regexp_split_to_array(hobby, '\s*,\s*') as hobbies from split_clm ) t $sql$ ;
  
  -- recreate the view
  execute 'drop view if exists clm_view cascade';
  execute 'create view clm_view as '||l_sql;    
end;
$body$ 
language plpgsql;
```

This will build a view that looks something like this:

```
select name, 
       'Athletics' = any(hobbies) as "Ahtletics",
       'Coding' = any(hobbies) as "Coding",  
       .....
from ( select name, regexp_split_to_array(hobby, '\s*,\s*') as hobbies from split_clm ) t;
```

Then run:

```
select create_normalized_view();
```

and to see the content:

```
select *
from clm_view;
```

Depending on how often the table is updated, you could call that function from a trigger or a cron job that updates the view in regular intervals.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/IjdOPhLG)

Comment: definitely, PostgreSQL has  a lot of new  function for me. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html
However, I am trying to see if  value (the one that brings number can be show in the table).  `select format('%L = any(hobbies) as %I', x.hobby_name, x.hobby_name)
,x.value  
 from (
    select distinct t.hobby_name ,s.value
    from split_clm s
      cross join unnest(regexp_split_to_array(s.hobby, '\s*,\s*')) as t(hobby_name)
  ) x;`