# Unexpected duplicates in result of crosstab function

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I am new to Postgres and the function `crosstab()`. I have query like this:

```
select * from crosstab(
  'select artis_clean, release_year, total_count_song from top_artis_5year ' ,
   'select distinct release_year from top_artis_5year order by 1 '
    
) as (
 "artis_clean" text, "1965" int , "1966" int, "1967" int, "1968" int,"1969" int,"1970" int
);
```

I get a result like this:

```
artis_clean     1965    1966    1967    1968    1969    1970
------------    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    -----
the beatles     null    null    23      null    null    null
led zepelin     null    null    null    null      18    null
the beatles       15    null    null    13        13    null
led zepelin       12    null    null    null    null    null
jimi hendrix    null    null    9       null    null    null
jimi hendrix       8    null    null    null    null    null
```

Why does `artis_clean` still have duplicate data, when I put `artis_clean` in the `distinct`?

```
 'select distinct release_year,artis_clean from top_artis_5year order by 1 '
```

The code won't work, Postgres says:

```
ERROR:  provided "categories" SQL must return 1 column of at least one row
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input needs to be sorted. Append `ORDER BY 1` to the first argument of your first query.

Also, it makes no sense to query all `release_year` dynamically for the second argument while the column definition list is static anyway.

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

To replace resulting NULL values, use `COALESCE` in the outer `SELECT`. Example:

- [Use row values as columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886327/use-row-values-as-columns-in-postgresql/22887033#22887033)

Comment: thank you, my query is work , then I want change null to 0, how is it ?

Comment: @dipretelin: I added to the answer.